# tomcat 7 not accessible and cannot shutdown

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

I created tomcat cluster and when i try to start tomcat it shows that tomcat started but i cannot access from localhost: and when i'm try to shutdown it i cannot shutdown it either.
please help me to solve this problem.

```
gaiz@ubuntu:~/softz/cluster$ ./startup-instance1.sh
    Using CATALINA_BASE:   /home/gaiz/softz/cluster/instance-1
    Using CATALINA_HOME:   /home/gaiz/softz/cluster/apache-tomcat-7.0.55
    Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /home/gaiz/softz/cluster/instance-1/temp
    Using JRE_HOME:        /usr
    Using CLASSPATH:       /home/gaiz/softz/cluster/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/bin/bootstrap.jar:/home/gaiz/softz/cluster/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
    Tomcat started.
```

and when i'm try to shutdown it this error occurs

```
gaiz@ubuntu:~/softz/cluster$ ./shutdown-instance1.sh
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /home/gaiz/softz/cluster/instance-1
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /home/gaiz/softz/cluster/apache-tomcat-7.0.55
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /home/gaiz/softz/cluster/instance-1/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr
Using CLASSPATH:       /home/gaiz/softz/cluster/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/bin/bootstrap.jar:/home/gaiz/softz/cluster/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Sep 12, 2014 9:13:42 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina stopServer
SEVERE: Could not contact localhost:8006. Tomcat may not be running.
Sep 12, 2014 9:13:42 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina stopServer
SEVERE: Catalina.stop: 
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.stopServer(Catalina.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.stopServer(Bootstrap.java:370)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:457)
```

Answer (score 1):

1. It's very likely that Tomcat is starting and failing but not immediately.  Hence your startup script thinks it's running, but when you try to stop the service it fails saying it cannot stop Tomcat because it isn't running.  After you start Tomcat, you could run `ps aux | grep catalina` and look to see if the process is still running.
2. Assuming it's failing, look for errors in your Tomcat logs. This will likely be at `/home/gaiz/softz/cluster/instance-1/logs`.  Check all of the logs, including `catalina.yyyy-mm-dd.log`, `catalina.out` and `localhost.yyyy-mm-dd.log`, as errors my be isolated to one of the log files.  Also check any application specific logs as you could have problems with the application too.